# jQuery plugin for repeating divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I access, div with class name fire in this for a function or in general access nested div class?

```
//this doesn't seems to work
function lightCandle(){

     $(".fire").show();
}



<div class="dom" id="dom" style="display: none">
    <div class="happydiwali" id="happydiwali">
            <div class="candle"></div>
            <div id="match" class="match"><a href="#match"> </a></div>
            <div class="fire" id="fire"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your parent `div` is in `display: none`. How the inner will display?. You should make the parent to `display: block`

Comment: from where you are calling `lightCandle()`?

Comment: lightCandle() is an onclick function for a button

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the `.fire` element but it's parent `.dom` element remains hidden because of the `display:none`.

Show the `.dom` element as well as `.fire`:

```
$(".fire").show().closest('.dom').show();
```

Comment: the program adds the number of candle as input by the user.....so as to display no candles at first, the display is none....when I put this code, it just adds one more candle but does not creates the fire div

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent to `display: block`, and to the child as well.

```
function lightCandle(){
    var dom = $(".dom");

    if(dom.css('display') == none){
        dom.css('display', 'block');
        dom.find('.fire').show();
    }


    //Or with out condition,
    dom.css('display', 'block');
    dom.find('.fire').show();

}
```

Comment: Are you initializing your `function lightCandle()`